# Broadcast Receiver in a service but intent not getting caught on service once process is killed

Tags: android, service, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a simple widget that does some calculations once the screen comes on and displays them and clears all the fields once the screen goes off ... i have a broadcast receiver setup in my service which listens to ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.

This works perfectly as long as the phone doesn't go to sleep for a long period of time or there is heavy usage of the phone - once this happens my widget process is killed (the service is still running but the process is killed) after this when the screen goes off and comes back on my widget doesn't update as the ACTION_SCREEN_ON intent is not caught by my service :(

```
public class CDTservice extends Service {

  @Override
   public void onCreate() {


        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        m_receiver = new ScreenBroadcastReceiver();
        registerReceiver(m_receiver, filter);
        Log.d("Widgettool", "works");
    }



  @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


start();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SERVICE ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }


     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
 stop();
      unregisterReceiver(m_receiver);
      }



     public void start()
       { 
RemoteViews View = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);   
updatewidgetclass x= new updatewidgetclass(this, View, widgetId);
x.start(); // does calculations and displays on widget
     }


      public void stop()
   {   
RemoteViews Viewclear = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

updatewidgetclass y = new updatewidgetclass(this, Viewclear, widgetId);
y.stop(); // clears resources and stops

}


   private class ScreenBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Log.d("ON SCREEN ON", "might hang here");   
        start();


     } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
       stop();

    }
    }

    }
```

sometimes when the widget process is not claimed by the android system the widget works perfectly for days and perfectly displays the values ACTION_SCREEN_ON

the problem arises when - i check in settings>apps>running - i can see my widget name and it says 0 processes and 1 service

i assume the broadcast receive is happening on the main process and hence its not receiving it when the process gets killed.

I have a work around in place for this but would really like to fix the issue.
Any helps is highly appreciated

Comment: http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/5281/screenshot2013052311325.png

Screenshot of running service

Comment: Tying up memory with a service every moment of the day, just so you can find out when the screen turns on and off, is user-hostile. Having an always-running service is an anti-pattern in Android development. Please find some other solution to whatever problem you think that you are solving.

Comment: if i have the broadcast receiver in the widget class then the intents for screen on are never delivered to the widget

Comment: Correct. The solution is to stop trying to receive screen-off and screen-on broadcasts. Those are designed *for use by the foreground application, not an app widget.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare i have re looked and changed my design. But i am still curious as to why if my service is still running, it does not detect the screen coming on ?? Is it that the process for the widget is getting killed and hence the service is unable to receive the broadcast ?? :s

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @CommonsWare that having a service running in the bg at all times just to detect when the screen turns on and off is a **very** bad idea. Do you really need `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`, or will `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` (phone unlocked) suffice? This way, you do not need a service at all, and you can just define the receiver in the manifest.

If you really wanted to, you could register your service/`ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`receiver in your `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` receiver so that the service is only running when the user is actually using the device.

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but it does provide a useful workaround to your problem.

Comment: i have actually come up with a new solution to my problem, but after reading your answer i have tried to use the ACTION_SCREEN_ON in my widget, but it doesn't receive the broadcast in a widget. To ensure that my code was correct i simply put it in a blank application to catch the ACTION_SCREEN_ON and display it as a toast. It works fine in an app, but doesn't work in the widget :s